# Django DB Relations

Tags: mysql, django, database

I apologize for the novice question but my head is about to explode.

I am trying to learn Django and wanted to create something practical and that I could use. I settled with a small inventory system.

The problem I am having is figuring out the best way to have relationships between models for ideal db setup.

I have models for the following:

- Depreciation Policy
- Manufacturer
- Customer/Owner
- Asset Category (Server, laptop etc)
- Asset Model (Macbook Pro, Proliant DL380 Gen 9 etc)
- Asset Status (Archived, Deployed, Lost etc)
- Asset Fields (Generic fields all assets would
  have, model(FK), status(FK), purchase date etc.)
- Cpu
- Server
- Network Card

Right now I have both Server & Network Card inheriting Asset Fields.

My goal was to have tables for each type of asset but still have one master table that can reference each asset type's table via a FK so that if I want to display all assets in the database I can just list one table and pull in the relevant information from their related tables instead of having to look through each asset's table.

I want something like:

### Asset Table:

---

id(pk), model(fk), status(fk), serial Number, purchase date, cost, location, server_id/network_card_id(fk)

### Server Table:

---

id(pk), customer, name, memory, cpu(fk), ilo_type, ilo_lic

Asset Model:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    # class Meta:
    #     abstract = True

    assetTag = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    model = models.ForeignKey(AssetModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    status = models.ForeignKey(AssetStatus, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    serialNumber = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    purchaseDate = models.DateTimeField('Date order was placed', blank=True)
    purchaseOrder = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    cost = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True)

    # location = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)

    def calculate_current_value(self, purchaseDate, cost):
        purchase_price = float(cost)
        months = self.model.depreciationPolicy.months

        if months > 0:
            days = months * 30
            depreciation_per_day = (float(cost) / days)
            days_owned = timezone.now() - purchaseDate

            value_lost = days_owned.days * depreciation_per_day
            current_asset_value = purchase_price - value_lost
            return round(current_asset_value, 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.serialNumber
```

Server Model:

```
class Server(Asset):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    memory = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cpu = models.ForeignKey(Cpu, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    ILOType = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=(('Std', 'Standard'), ('Adv', 'Advanced')))
    ILOUsername = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    ILOPassword = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    ILOLicense = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.serialNumber
```

Network_Card Model:

```
class Nic(Asset):
    macAddress = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    portCount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    portType = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=(('Ethernet', 'Ethernet'), ('Fiber', 'Fiber')))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would recommend is for you to just forget about tables. You're not dealing with tables in Django, but with models, which are classes that represent the entities of your system. Models become tables later, but you don't have to concern yourself with them right now.

Second, model your classes carefully. Design a nice diagram representing their relationships. In your scenario, one class will contain references to other classes (a pivot class), so model that.

Also, take a moment to read the documentation. Django is a very neatly and thoroughly documented. Read carefully about models and squerysets. You will know everything you need to represent things inside your architecture.

Some hints:

When defining foreign fields, you'll have quite a few options, from ForeighKey(), ManyToManyField(), ManyToOneRel(), etc. Read about each and every one of the options, and chose the one that represents your reality most accurately.

ManyToMany() has an interesting behavior, which is: if you don't pass a table to it, it will create one for you, to act as a pivot. I prefer to create my middle tables, as it is more aligned with the Zen of Python.

When you want to return a coherent representation of  your data, you'll have to work with querysets in order to enforce the relationships you have built into your models, much in the same way you'd do with a relational database, either by constructing a query, or designing a view.

Here's some nice links for you:

- Fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/
- Querysets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/
- The Zen of Python: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Further, I strongly recommend you to go take a look at Django Rest Framework as soon as you get a hold on the basic concepts of Django models. Here's the link: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

And come back to me when you have more specific questions.

Happy coding!

Comment: I really appreciate this, I haven't had much time to work on it or look through these but I will accept this answer since it is, in my mind the correct thing I should do at this juncture. Thank you for the links, I will try to get a better understanding of the underlying technology before proceeding!

Comment: @Chex, I'm glad I could help. Please feel free to com back to me later if you need further assistance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved this issue. 
the solution was to build it out as follows. Instead of the Server & Nic class inheriting the Asset class, I defined a 1:1 relationship with  each of them and the Asset class.

```
asset = models.OneToOneField(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

This allowed for the Asset table to track all assets, and the asset_id(PK) is both a foreign_key and a primary_key in Server & Nic.